# Unable to get custom hook data from within Debounce

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, lodash, debouncing

```js
import { debounce  } from 'lodash';

const App = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useTestState();

  const handleSearchKeyword = (keyword: string) => {
    setText(keyword);
    sendQuery();
  };

  const sendQuery = useCallback(
    debounce(() => {
      console.log(text);
    }, 1000),
    []
  );

  return <input type="text" onChange={handleSearchKeyword} />;
};

const useTestState = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  return [text, setText];
};
```

function setData does work normally

however, null is printed in sendQuery  function

I want to know why it's not working on debounce.

Answer (score 0):

According to your current code `sendQuery` will use the same value of text no matter how many times you set it, i.e the value of `useCallback` is memoized since you haven't set any dependencies.

You need to pass `text` as a dependency in `useCallback` like this.

```
 const handleSearchKeyword = (keyword: string) => {
    setText(keyword);
    
    debounce(sendQuery, 5000);
  };

  const sendQuery = useCallback(
      () => {
          console.log(text);
      },
      [text]
  );
```

Edit: You can call debounce in handleSearchKeyword function or as @Ori Drori pointed out, just pass text as parameter to debounce function scope to fix debouncing

Comment: Thank you for answer. But if you do this, I think the debounce not work.

Comment: @jayjay Then just set the debounce in `handleSearchKeyword` when you are calling `sendQuery`

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because the debounced function was declared in the scope in which `text` was an empty string. Since the debounced function isn't redeclared when `text` changes, it will always show the original value.

You can redeclare it when `text` changes, but that would mass up the debounce, since it requires the function to be same, so this **doesn't work**:

```
const sendQuery = useCallback(
  debounce(() => {
    console.log(text);
  }, 1000),
  [text] // creates a new function whenever text changes
);
```

The easiest solution in this case is to pass `keyword` as a parameter to the debounced function:

```
const sendQuery = useCallback(
  debounce(text => { // text is a parameter now
    console.log(text);
  }, 1000), []
);

const handleSearchKeyword = (keyword: string) => {
  setText(keyword);
  sendQuery(keyword); // pass keyword
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, but that's what I've already tried.

Comment: It's not.  Look at the comments.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [stale props/state problem](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function) described in the React hooks FAQ.

A nice solution is to use [the "latest state" ref boxing pattern](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#what-can-i-do-if-my-effect-dependencies-change-too-often) described in the FAQ (search for "last resort"):

```
import { debounce } from "lodash";

const App = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const latestText = React.useRef();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    latestText.current = text;
  }, [text]);

  const handleSearchKeyword = (keyword: string) => {
    setText(keyword);
    sendQuery();
  };

  const sendQuery = useCallback(
    debounce(() => {
      console.log(latestText.current);
    }, 1000),
    [],
  );

  return <input type="text" onChange={handleSearchKeyword} />;
};
```

This can be bundled up into a custom hook if you like:

```
function useStateWithLatest(initial) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initial);
  const latest = React.useRef(initial);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    latest.current = value;
  }, [value]);
  return [value, setValue, latest];
}

const App = () => {
  const [text, setText, latestText] = useStateWithLatest("");

  const handleSearchKeyword = (keyword: string) => {
    setText(keyword);
    sendQuery();
  };

  const sendQuery = useCallback(
    debounce(() => {
      console.log(latestText.current);
    }, 1000),
    [],
  );

  return <input type="text" onChange={handleSearchKeyword} />;
};
```